# pagination in php for (isset($_REQUEST['start_page']))

Tags: php, pagination

i am not able to understand how the last_record and start_point will get

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['start_page'])){

        $last_record = $_REQUEST['start_page'] * $_REQUEST['limit'];
        $start_point = $last_record - $_REQUEST['limit'];
    }
    else
    {
        $start_point= 0;
        $last_record= 5;            
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['limit'])){
        $limit = $_REQUEST['limit']; 
    }
    else
    {
        $limit = 5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this demo will work for you http://demos.9lessons.info/pagination.php